# How much does the server logs about client window pc with proxy server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, proxy

I have joined new job and here its the big govt department.
They have server 2008 as server with proxy server for all internet access.

Now my home internet connection is dialup and i will get broadband coonection within 2 months.
Now i download lot of stuff and i want to do the same feom my work pc.

Now i want to know that doe server logs which site i have visits an dhow much data i have downloaded from each site.

The other option i am thinking is that i have the virtual server wher ei have unlimited Bandwidth.

So what i can do is download my stuff to my virtual server and then from there i download to my work PC and take the data home.

In case someone asks me then i will say that it was my stuff which i need for working.

I also have ubuntu virtual machine where i test my stuff and i had to use shuttle in there for internet

Any ideas

Comment: It sounds like you're tring to skirt some policy or hide your activity from the people who manage the work network, which isn't going to go over very well here.

Comment: It also sounds like an end user question, which is off topic.

Comment: `Any ideas`  I have plenty, but to be honest, they mostly involve advising you to do things that would get you fired or arrested, because that seems like the best case scenario for everyone.  Some guy who thinks he's above the rules shouldn't be part of the organization that makes the rules I'm forced to follow (sometimes called "the law).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proxy server administrator can see every site you visit and every URL you download. It is trivial for the administrator to determine if you are violating policy, or worse, local laws. And you may find that many web sites not related to work are blocked.

I recommend you do your home stuff at home, and your work stuff at work, and keep them physically separated.

It sounds like you're just trying to use the work connection to download large files, since you only have dialup at home. In this case I would recommend you use an Internet cafe, until you get a broadband connection installed at home.

Comment: if i download stuff via scp , wget , rsync, from linux ssh , does it still knows that

Comment: You just got the job! How quickly do you want to get fired? :)

Comment: @MichaelHampton  As quickly as possible, it seems.  Stop interfering with the guy's wishes. :p